# 2013 CSR SPClientTemplates Add Delay

Tags: 2013, client-side-rendering, angularjs

I'm trying to add an override using SPClientTemplates but by the time my custom code calls RegisterTemplateOverrides it's too late, the CSR has already been processed. If I add my custom code to a Script Editor it works fine, but that's not what I want. I need it to be called after other things have been processed, essentially on demand or via callback.

I tried looking at clienttemplates.debug.js but I couldn't see a way to achieve what I need. Perhaps I'm just missing something?

Full disclosure I'm trying to make template modifications using angularjs directives, but again by the time angular has finished bootstrapping, the CSR is taking a nap.

Answer (score 1):

I often use CSR to just set up placeholders in the right place on the page that I then access later through the custom IDs that I set.  So my CSR scripts look a bit like:

```
var DEC = DEC || {};

DEC.myOverride = (function () {

  function setUpFields(ctx) {
    // set up placeholders with custom IDs
    html = '<div id="MyDiv_' + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + '"></div>';
    return html;
  }

  function doLaterProcessing() {
    // retrieve the elements based on the IDs i set up earlier
    // and do whatever else I need to with them here.
    // this could include starting off a chain of async calls that
    // eventually populates the elements with data 
  }

  return {
    render: function () {
      SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        Templates: {
          Fields: {
            "MyField": {
              View: setUpFields,
            },
          },
        },
      });
    },
    postProcess: doLaterProcessing
  }
})();

RegisterModuleInit("/path/to/my/OverrideScript.js", DEC.myOverride.render);
DEC.myOverride.render();

// then trigger the later stuff later, either by:

$(window).load(function () {
  DEC.myOverride.postProcess();
});

// or:

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('DEC.myOverride.postProcess');
```

Not sure if that will work for you, but that's the technique I use to "use CSR" while still doing a lot of stuff *after* the CSR rendering has finished.

Comment: Interesting technique but it doesn't really achieve what I need. I may use this for other things though, thanks!